# ListView with AlertDialog non-responsive OnClickListener with no errors - was working

Tags: android

This is a ListView with AlertDialog for a Bills app which pops up with options to pay, edit, or delete when when each list item is clicked. then you select "pay" or "edit" it then gathers the corrosponding data for that option before redireccting to another activity. when delete is selected a different AlertDialog appears for confirmation before deleting.

I had this working just fine (listView items were clickable), but now nothing. I've gone over my code over and over and I'm stumped.
I'm sure it will end up being something small, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

```
final Context context = this;
    ArrayList<BillArray> bills = db.getBillArray();

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, bills));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final BillArray fullObject = (BillArray)o;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You've chosen: "+" "+ fullObject.getVendor(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final CharSequence[] items = { "Pay Bill", "Edit", "Delete" };

              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
              builder.setTitle("Options for:\n"+ fullObject.getVendor());
              builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
              builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item] + " selected", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      if(items[item] == "Pay Bill"){
                          // LOAD "PAY BILL" PAGE

                          Intent payBill = new Intent(context, PayBillActivity.class);
                          payBill.putExtra("id", fullObject.getId());
                          payBill.putExtra("vendor", fullObject.getVendor());
                          payBill.putExtra("acct", fullObject.getAcct());
                          payBill.putExtra("payment", fullObject.getPayment());
                          payBill.putExtra("mindue", fullObject.getMinDue());
                          payBill.putExtra("tDue", fullObject.getTdue());
                          payBill.putExtra("tBal", fullObject.getTbal());

                          final int result = 1;
                            startActivityForResult(payBill, result);
                      }

                      if(items[item] == "Edit"){
                          // LOAD "EDIT" PAGE

                          Intent editBill = new Intent(context, EditBillActivity.class);
                          editBill.putExtra("id", fullObject.getId());
                          editBill.putExtra("vendor", fullObject.getVendor());
                          editBill.putExtra("acct", fullObject.getAcct());
                          editBill.putExtra("payment", fullObject.getPayment());
                          editBill.putExtra("typePos", fullObject.getTypePos());
                          editBill.putExtra("billType", fullObject.getBillType());
                          editBill.putExtra("billDay", fullObject.getBillDay());
                          editBill.putExtra("mindue", fullObject.getMinDue());
                          editBill.putExtra("amtPaid", fullObject.getAmtPaid());
                          editBill.putExtra("tDue", fullObject.getTdue());
                          editBill.putExtra("tBal", fullObject.getTbal());

                          final int result = 1;
                            startActivityForResult(editBill, result);
                      }

                      if(items[item] == "Delete"){
                          // POP-UP CONFIRMATION DIALOG W/ "DELETE" AND "CANCEL" BUTTON
                          AlertDialog.Builder delCon = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                          delCon.setTitle("DELETE " + fullObject.getVendor() + "?");
                          delCon.setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                db.deleteBill(fullObject);

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DELETED",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Intent intent = getIntent();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                          });                             
                          delCon.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DELETION CANCELLED",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }                                 
                          });
                          AlertDialog confirm = delCon.create();
                          confirm.show();
                      }
                  }
              });
              AlertDialog alert = builder.create();               
              alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of research, several trial/errors and several fist-fulls of hair ;) I found the answer to my problem!

I tried using: listView.setClickable(true), but that didn't work. I then went to my listView_layout.xml file and tried adding focusable="false" to no avail!

I then realized I forgot to remove the listView.setClickable(true) which I had set earlier,
so I removed it then ran the application and to my amazement IT WORKED!

My listView items were clickable again which brought up my AlertDialog and all was well.

But then I also realized all the elements on my listView_layout were textViews and "inputType" was completely unneccessary!(Copy & Paste error) So I tried removing all of my "inputTypes" AND "focusable" attributes then I ran my app again and listView was still good and clickable.

So, if you have "inputType" attributes inside of the elements of your listView_layout, be sure to
to add: android:focusable="false" inside of those elements as well. Make sure you aren't making any "clickable" calls inside java which will conflict with your xml.

Also, when you copy and paste, be sure you don't leave anything that shouldn't be there like I have.

I hope this helps the many who are having OnItemClickListener problems. Good Luck!